# I can't find the javascript in main bracket in bower

Tags: bower

I already added the dependency of blueimp-file-upload in my bower file. ( bower.json)

```
{
    "name": "redca-admin-web",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "RedCA Admin frontend implementation",
    "authors": [
        "redca <redca@samsung.com>"
    ],
    "main": "index.html",
    "license": "MIT",
    "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "test",
        "tests"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": ">=1.6",
        "jquery-ui": ">=1.6",
        "rdash-ui": "1.0.*",
        "angular": "~1.2.21",
        "angular-cookies": "~1.2.28",
        "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
        "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.10",
        "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
        "font-awesome": "~4.1.0",
        "angular-route": "~1.2.28",
        "angular-resource": "~1.2.28",
        "font-awesome": "~4.1.0",
        "blueimp-file-upload" : "9.9.3"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/rdash/rdash-angular"
    }
}
```

and I installed the dependency with the command, "bower install" and I can confirmed the dependencies in the folder, "src/components". But I can't find the 
classes in main bracket in the followings. I saw the explanation of bower main page that the java script files in the main bracket are heavily used files.

> main string or array: The primary acting files necessary to use your
>   package.

I am confused whether or not I misunderstood. Should I download the library that contains java-script files in main bracket separately?

```
{
  "name": "blueimp-file-upload",
  "version": "9.9.3",
  "title": "jQuery File Upload",
  "description": "File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bar, validation and preview images, audio and video for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads. Works with any server-side platform (Google App Engine, PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.",
  "keywords": [
    "jquery",
    "file",
    "upload",
    "widget",
    "multiple",
    "selection",
    "drag",
    "drop",
    "progress",
    "preview",
    "cross-domain",
    "cross-site",
    "chunk",
    "resume",
    "gae",
    "go",
    "python",
    "php",
    "bootstrap"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload",
  "author": {
    "name": "Sebastian Tschan",
    "url": "https://blueimp.net"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "Sebastian Tschan",
      "url": "https://blueimp.net"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.git"
  },
  "bugs": "https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.6",
    "blueimp-tmpl": ">=2.5.4",
    "blueimp-load-image": ">=1.13.0",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": ">=2.1.1"
  },
  "main": [
    "css/jquery.fileupload.css",
    "css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css",
    "css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css",
    "css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css",
    "js/cors/jquery.postmessage-transport.js",
    "js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js",
    "js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-process.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-image.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-video.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-jquery-ui.js",
    "js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js",
    "js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "/*.*",
    "/cors",
    "css/demo-ie8.css",
    "css/demo.css",
    "css/style.css",
    "js/app.js",
    "js/main.js",
    "server",
    "test"
  ],
  "_release": "9.9.3",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "9.9.3",
    "commit": "d4b0492c6e0ba77b446a3bfb2847a0a4827a9c08"
  },
  "_source": "https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.git",
  "_target": "9.9.3"
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the main files of the blueimp-file-upload dependency? where did you look for the missing files?

Comment: I was looking the main files in the directory where the bower brought the components. "src\components". But it wasn't there. I think it depends on the case. I should have imported the classes that has the java script in main bracket.